# read @Value from service - springboot SpEL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

I tried following code :

```java
@Autowired
private ParameterService parameterService;

@Value("#{parameterService.findByCode('value1')}")
private String valueOne;

private Test test = Test.getInstance(valueOne); //this shows nullpointer exception
```

service's `findByCode` method reads the value from the database and returns.

However, it seems that `value` is always null. Is it possible to do this in this way? or How should I do this?

Comment: How about usinig `@Value("#{@parameterService.findByCode('value1')}")` (and not even wiring it as a field?)

Comment: It is not working

Comment: Is your `findByCode` actually being invoked?  If you say it's always `null` it can be caused by the invocation returning `null` or the wiring that's not working.